# Transposing complex DataFrame in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a pandas DataFrame composed of a list of objects and then 4 lists of 12 values for each object. It has the general form:

[image: Current Data]

I would like to transpose the dataframe and have hierarchical indices ('Name', 'names of 4 lists'). The general form of this would look like [image: Desired Result]

I have tried the following, with rows_list being my source data:

```
import pandas as pd

test_table = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=("name", "frac_0", "frac_1","frac_2", "frac_3"))

name = pd.Series(test_table['name'])

del test_table['name']
test_table = test_table.T
test_table = test_table.sort_index([subjectname])
```

This gives me a TypeError that states

> "unhashable type: 'list'".

A simple `test_table.T` operation also doesn't give me what I need, as I need columns to correspond to items in the (*List1, List2,* etc) lists, and the rows to be indexed by name and then *List1, List2*. I've gone back and forth with adding new columns, or trying to build a brand new DataFrame from multiple series, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should provide a sample of the data frame, we cant test `test_table` because we don't have `row_list` variable. Please read how to make a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) so that someone can better assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Mock df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'List 1', 'List 2'], data=[['A', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], ['B', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], ['C', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]])
```

Get 'Name' out of the way:

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

                List 1        List 2
    Name                            
    A     [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
    B     [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]
    C     [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3, 4]

n_name = len(df.index)
n_list = len(df.columns)
n_item = len(df.iat[0, 0])
```

The df values now has a shape of (3,2). We need to reshape to, in this mock df, a (6,) array to remove one dimension. We then make it a list.

```
vals = list(df.values.reshape((n_list * n_name),))

[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Now we get the values for the index levels. Since 'Name' is the first level, we want that level repeated by the number of unique values in the next level, so we use repeat. The level with lists, we want to maintain order, so we use tile. Then your column names are added:

```
idx_name = np.repeat(df.index.values, n_list)
idx_list = np.tile(df.columns.values, n_name)
columns = ['Col' + str(n) for n in list(range(1, n_item+1))]
```

Create final df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=vals, index=[idx_name, idx_list], columns=columns)

          Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
A List 1     1     2     3     4
  List 2     1     2     3     4
B List 1     1     2     3     4
  List 2     1     2     3     4
C List 1     1     2     3     4
  List 2     1     2     3     4
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'List 1', 'List 2'], data=[['A', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], ['B', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], ['C', [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]])

df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

n_name = len(df.index)
n_list = len(df.columns)
n_item = len(df.iat[0, 0])

vals = list(df.values.reshape((n_list * n_name),))
idx_name = np.repeat(df.index.values, n_list)
idx_list = np.tile(df.columns.values, n_name)
columns = ['Col' + str(n) for n in list(range(1, n_item+1))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=vals, index=[idx_name, idx_list], columns=columns)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I am still trying to understand exactly what you did in the second half as there are some functions I am unfamiliar with, but thank you so much!